# AWS: Adding Correct Inbound Security Groups to RDS and EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to use a mysql RDS in an EC2 instance. I believe my security group configuration might be wrong. For some reason the RDS is not connecting.

My EC2 instance includes the following inbound groups: 
1) HTTP (port 80), 
2) SSH (port 22), 
3) MYSQL/AURA (port 3306) - I added the security group from the RDS in source,
4) Custom TCP Rule (port 3000)

My RSD instance includes the following inbound groups: 
1) HTTP (port 80) - I also tried port 3000 but that didn't work, 
2) MYSQL/AURA (port 3306)

In my db config file, when I try to add a callback to the connection I got an "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT". I then changed my connection to a pool connection but that didn't work either. Any insight on why my RSD isn't connecting in my EC2 instance would be appreciated. Thank you

[image: EC2 Snapshot]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your EC2 Security Group remove the rules for port 3306. RDS does not connect to you. You connect to RDS. I don't know what port 3000 is for. Plus for port 3000 you only configured an IPv6 rule. Remove it unless you have a specific reason.

For your RDS Security Group remove port 80. RDS only supports the port that you assigned in the AWS Console. The default for MySQL on RDS is 3306. Double check what you configured in the console and configure accordingly. For the inbound rule on port 3306 you can specify the security group ID that is attached to the EC2 instance. This will only allow EC2 <-> RDS.

When connecting to RDS, use the RDS DNS endpoint. You will find this in the AWS RDS Console. Do not use TCP/IP addresses for your connection string.